# cp: cannot stat '{1..112046}.pth': No such file or directory

Tags: files, directory, copy, cp

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to copy the range of files from one directory to another directory.

```
cp {1..112046}.pth path/to/destination_folder
```

While being inside the source folder. But it keeps giving me an error

```
cp: cannot stat '{1..112046}.pth': No such file or directory
```

I tried giving the absolute path of both the source and destination folders but nothing worked.

A sample of how my files look like in a folder:

```
186811.pth  273630.pth  361833.pth  448804.pth  536862.pth  99989.pth
186815.pth  273634.pth  361840.pth  448811.pth  536865.pth  99994.pth
186819.pth  273643.pth  361841.pth  448817.pth  53686.pth
```

I need help to resolve this error.

Comment: Add the output of `echo $0 $SHELL` to your question, please. Use code formatting for commands and command output: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: The error may be only for the files in range 1..112046 that _do not_ appear in the current directory. Have you checked any matching files that are copied to the destination directory?

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli when I copy the files separately they work but given the range it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you are not using BASH (as the first comment suggested). What is the output of `echo $0`? Try to use the command `bash -c 'cp {1..112046}.pth path/to/destination_folder'`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yes this command worked. Thank you